# TFVC does not appear in source control VS Code

Tags: tfvc

As shown in the image, TFVC changes are detected but I can't open it to see included and excluded changes and check in

any help?
 [VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6yyu.png)

Comment: Have you tried refresh button, to refresh the project or repository of VS?

Comment: I can't find it in the TFVC, it just exists in the git repos